# Averaging equation?

Tags: average

Is there any name for following averaging equation and how does it work?

$$
y_{i+1} = (1-\alpha)\times y_i + x_i 
$$

I'm using it to average a signal, but I'm not sure am I interpreting the results right.

Comment: Can you describe why you need to average this signal?  Do you mean that you're smoothing a signal?

Comment: What is $x_i$ and what is $y_i$?

Comment: $x_i$ is a sample from signal. $y_i$ is a previously value of averaged $y$ and $y_{i+1}$ is next averaged value from $y$.

@littleO No, I'm not smoothing a signal, so I'm not looking for a averaging filter. I just should see that when the signal values get stronger $y_i$ should get stronger also. So it should be able to detect changes in signals strength.